# How to generate subsets

Tags: ampl

I would like to create different subsets for a set that is defined and store them to use them later in my modeling. For example, say I got C = {1,2,3}, is there any efficient way to get SC = {{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}} and use them later in a constraint?

It's specifically to solve unconnected circuits in the Traveling Salesman Problem (so any suggestion to solve it alternatively is well received). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetPowerSet<T>(List<T> list)
{
  return from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)
         select
           from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)
           where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
           select list[i];
}`

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

Famous one-liner in Haskell:

```
> filterM (const [True, False]) [1,2,3]
[[1,2,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1],[2,3],[2],[3],[]]
```